# generate a column in Pandas based on another column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = { 'name': ['ray', 'ray', 'ray', 'ray', 'ray', 'ray'], 
            'code': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1] }

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Initialize the 'Period' column
df['Period'] = 0

# Calculate the 'Period' based on the logic
current_period = 0 
for i in range(len(df)): 
    if df.loc[i, 'code'] == 1: 
        current_period += 1 
    else: 
        current_period = 0 
    df.loc[i, 'Period'] = current_period

# Display the DataFrame with the 'Period' column
print(df)
```

Above is my code, here I want to create period column based on values of code column.
The logic for period column is;

- first row is code=1 so period is 1,
- second row is code=0 so period is 0,
- then row 3 and 4 is code=1 so period is 2 for both rows
- 5th row is code=0 so period is 0, and
- then row 6 has code =1 so period is 3 and so on

Basically I want to group continuous rows with code=1 and assign a value to them.

[Check this for required output and my current output from the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDp2B.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use boolean operations with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), and [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
# Identify 1s
m1 = df['code'].eq(1)
# Identify first 1 of each stretch
m2 = m1&~m1.shift(fill_value=False)

# compute the increment, mask non-1s with 0
df['Period'] = m2.cumsum().where(m1, 0)
```

Output:

```
  name  code  Period
0  ray     1       1
1  ray     0       0
2  ray     1       2
3  ray     1       2
4  ray     0       0
5  ray     1       3
```

Intermediates:

```
  name  code     m1  ~m1.shift     m2  m2.cumsum  Period
0  ray     1   True       True   True          1       1
1  ray     0  False      False  False          1       0
2  ray     1   True       True   True          2       2
3  ray     1   True      False  False          2       2
4  ray     0  False      False  False          2       0
5  ray     1   True       True   True          3       3
```

##### fix of your code

You would need to keep track of the last value.

```
current_period = 0
last_period = 0
for i in range(len(df)): 
    if df.loc[i, 'code'] == 1:
        if last_period == 0:
            current_period += 1
            last_period = 1
        df.loc[i, 'Period'] = current_period
    else: 
        last_period = 0
```

But, you shouldn't use a loop with pandas.

Comment: Hey currently I only have one name is the dataframe i.e ray. Suppose I had 2 more different names in the dataframe then in that case I want the period values to start from 1 for each new name.
For eg: Period values for ray ---> 1,2,3
period values for jay ---> 1,2 and so on
How to initialize period value from 1 for each new name in dataframe?

Comment: Then you should use `m2.groupby(df['name']).cumsum().where(m1, 0)`